# Spring Boot 3 support with Activiti

Tags: java, spring-boot, activiti, workflow-engine

Can anyone please provide information on the compatibility of Spring Boot version 3.x with the [Activiti framework](https://www.activiti.org/)? I have checked the official documentation of Activiti but could not find any specific information regarding the compatibility of these two. I have also looked for answers on the [Activiti forum](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-process-services/spring-boot-3-support-with-activiti/td-p/315788), but haven't found a response to the same question.

I have seen some [examples](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/tree/develop/activiti-examples) from the Activiti github repo which are having spring boot version 2.7.6

Comment: They are currently only publishing release candidates for SB3 support, it will come in version 7.12 of Activiti.

Comment: Version 8 supports Spring Boot 3. See https://activiti.gitbook.io/activiti-7-developers-guide/releases/8.0.0